# Loss of numerical keypad to enter alarm times

Tags: iphone, ios, alarm

For a while within the past year, I was delighted to find that my iPhone allowed me to enter an alarm time using a numerical keypad instead of the simulated dials.  Now, it has reverted to the dials.  I wonder whether it is because I recently upgraded from iOS 14.4 to 15.2.1.

Was this in fact determined by the iOS version?

I'm a fan of installing as few apps as possible, and relying on native functionality.  Is there any way to get the numerical keypad back without installing an app?

Comment: Yes iOS 15 returned it back to the dials as feedback was negative towards typing in the time when it was introduced in iOS 13(?) or iOS 14... I don't think there's a setting you can change to use the keypad by default, but you can tap the dial and it'll let you key in the time instead of using the dial picker

Comment: @AVelj: So sad (for me).  When I tap the dial at the vertical center, nothing happens.  If I tap above or below the center, the tapped number moves to the centre becomes the selected digit.  But there are only two numbers above and below the centre.  By the way, did you want to post your comment as the answer?

Comment: So when you tap, it'll still show up the same (with the dial picker), but the keypad should pop up and you can just type in the time you want using the keypad. Is that what is showing for you? Doesn't bother me, answering as a comment... can't be bothered typing out a carefully formatted answer right now.

Comment: OK.  I might post it then.  But after I get an good understanding.  I see no keypad when I tap the dial.  Odd.  I wonder if the iOS has more limited functionality on iPhone SE.

Comment: It shouldn't, just make sure you tap exactly on the dial picker (not above/below) and the keypad should pop up.

Comment: "Hey Siri. Set alarm for 7.30am." Done.

Comment: @AVelj: You're right!  So great!  Happy days are here again.......thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No - the interface has changed, though.

Thanks to *AVelj*'s comment, I found that if I tap directly on the number that is selected by the dial picker, I get a number pad.  I can then enter (say) `900` and get a 9am alarm.